# Morgan Logging - Is it possible to log User name from request header ? How?

Tags: node.js, morgan

```
app.use(morgan(function (tokens, req, res) {
console.log(req)
try {
    let logData = {
        morganLogStream: [
            tokens['date'](req, res),
            ' Type-', tokens.method(req, res, 'Type'),
            ' Url-', tokens.url(req, res).split('?')[0],
            ' Status-', tokens.status(req, res),
            ' Content_Length-', tokens.res(req, res, 'content-length'),
            ' Response_Time-', tokens['response-time'](req, res), 'ms',
        ].join('')
    }

}))
```

I am using Basic Auth with kerberos. I can see authorization header but not able to fetch the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best I could do was this:

`new Buffer(req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1], 'base64').toString('ascii').split(':')[0] : ''`

Which returns user name. I wish thr was any direct option in morgan library.